# Pipeline permissions issue when writing to node_modules directory

Tags: git, docker, jenkins

I am trying to build a pipeline from Git to my docker host and am running a jenkinsfile on git to push out an image and start the container.  My pipeline has hit a snag in the form of a permissions issue which the error clearly states in the log.  I added the sudo line that the error complains about inside of the golive script.  I am wondering if this needs to be actually run within the container itself when it is spun up?  If someone can give me a tip or a clue on how to accomplish this or add this to a different stage or step I would highly appreciate it.  Thank you

```
+ npm install

npm ERR! code EACCES

npm ERR! syscall mkdir

npm ERR! path /.npm

npm ERR! errno EACCES

npm ERR! 

npm ERR! Your cache folder contains root-owned files, due to a bug in

npm ERR! previous versions of npm which has since been addressed.

npm ERR! 

npm ERR! To permanently fix this problem, please run:

npm ERR!   sudo chown -R 113:119 "/.npm"

script returned exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Jenkins wiz, but it seems the user in running the script in container is not root and with a work dir at / then it can't create /.npm

I solved with adding a user to the docker arg like this:

```
agent {
    docker {
        image 'node:15-alpine'
        args '-u root:root'
        reuseNode true
    }
}
```